# Can I say "I'll make my effort to not forget it"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Can I say "I'll make my effort **to not** forget it"?

My doubt is on the words "to not", because I don't know if it's possible (correctly) to put adverb after preposition and I'm not used to hear it from people, but it's very needed for me a lot of times to use such sentence.

Comment: In typical conversations, *I'll do/try my best not to forget it*, *I won't forget it*, or even *I'll not forget it* would be more common. (But note that these convey subtly different shades of meaning.) Also note that rather than just *make my effort*, it's more common to use *I'll make my best effort not to forget it*. In my opinion, *I'll make my effort to not forget it* is not wrong, but it's highly marked (unusual).

Comment: *I'll make an effort to not forget it* sounds much better.  We know *an effort* is the speaker's effort. However, for some reason *I'll make my best effort to not forget it* is felicitous, since *a best effort* is not the commonest English, although *the best effort* also works.

Answer (score 2):

> because I don't know if it's possible (correctly) to put adverb after preposition

"to" is not functioning as a preposition in "to not forget it". It is an **infinitive** particle there.

Split infinitives (i.e. stuffing adverbs, e.g. not, boldly, outright, really, etc. between "to" and the infinitive it works with) are perfectly acceptable.

> The population is expected **to** *more than* **double** in the next twenty years.
>
> James's response is **to** *quietly* **move on**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive

Comment: I know you have covered the part the OP asked about, but it might be nice to cover "make my effort" too.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost, Thank you. So is it acceptable to say ""I'll make my best effort *to not* forget it"?

Comment: @Assiduous yep, that's fine.

Comment: Thank you. So, if you can to your original answer the difference between "to not" and not to" (as in the comment of Damkerng), I would thank you so much. I am not sure what is more acceptable.

Comment: Assiduous,  "to not forget" is wrong.  To produce the negative form of a "to infinitive", you place "not" before the  to infinitive.

Comment: Examples:  not to forget/ ;  not to do/;  not  to eat/;  not to go...etc

Comment: @lalynacar. Splitting infinitives is completely acceptable even with *not*.

Comment: *I'll make my best effort to not forget it* is okay, but *I'll make my effort to not forget it* sounds strange and unnatural; in this case *an effort* sounds more natural: we know it's your effort simply because you are the one saying the sentence.